# Правило постановки приставок в, во, над, надо, под, подо, от, ото, раз и разо

Tags: словообразование, грамматика

В каком случае используется та или иная приставка:

под- или подо-

над- или надо-

в- или во-

от- или ото-

раз- или разо-

Я попытался найти правило для постановки приставок в интернете, но, к сожалению, так и не нашел его.

Comment: Одно из правил этого сайта: "Не используйте подписи, статусы и приветствия"

Answer (score 1):

Если корень из 1 слога и в нём есть чередование гласного с нулём звука, то в приставке тоже обычно имеется чередование о/нуль звука. **Гласный в приставке появляется  там, где в корне нуль звука и наоборот.** Вбирать-вобрать(в-бир/во-бр);обдирать-ободрать (об-дир/обо-др)

Приставки могут быть как открытыми(на конце гласный), так и закрытыми(на конце согласный).Закрытые приставки **перед сочетанием согласных** становятся открытыми. Чередование объясняется наличием в приставках в древнерусском языке редуцированного гласного Ъ, в сильной позиции он переходил в О, в слабой утрачивался. Раз-рывать / разо-рвать.